# Launch macros one by one from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, imacros

In Firefox, Using Imacros, I would like to launch multiple macros from a batch file but here is the problem: I want them to run one by one. 
So first 'Macro 1' will run then after it completes, 'Macro 2' will run and so on till 'Macro 7'.

My BATCH CODE:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox
start firefox.exe 
ping -n 05 127.0.0.1>nul
start firefox.exe imacros://run/?m=NAMEofMACRO.iim

Imacros VERSION BUILD=7601105
```

Comment: Do you have a batch command that you use to run a single macro?

Comment: I added the code in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change your macro line to use the `start` switch `/wait`

```
start /wait firefox.exe imacros://run/?m=NAMEofMACRO.iim
start /wait firefox.exe imacros://run/?m=NAMEofNextMACRO.iim
start /wait firefox.exe imacros://run/?m=NAMEofNextMACRO.iim
```

That will launch each one, wait for it to finish, then start the next.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, inside imacros, is to add at the and of each macro.iim the line

```
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=NAMEofNextMACRO.iim
```

So you have to run just the first macro; this macro, at the end will call the second, and the second, at the end, will call the third, and so on...