# create a batch file to open firefox, then run a macro (wait for it to finish) then run another macro

Tags: batch-file, imacros

I am trying to:
(1) load Firefox
(2) run Iopus Imacro (.iim) - wait for this to finish, then
(3) run the next macro.

So far I have tried start /wait - call and as many other suggestions as I could find all over the internet and this is what I have so far (which runs flawlessly - as long as there is only one macro file (.iim) to play):

```
@ECHO ON
ECHO
ECHO You have 5 sec to close this Window to prevent the Macro from running...
timeout 5
ECHO Start Firefox and wait another 10 seconds...
start /B "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
timeout 10
ECHO Now running the macro (in a 2nd Tab)...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="mymacro1.iim"

rem Macro Execution completed
ECHO FINISHED!
```

When I try to add more files to run, like this:

```
@ECHO ON
ECHO
ECHO You have 5 sec to close this Window to prevent the Macro from running...
timeout 5
ECHO Start Firefox and wait another 10 seconds...
start /B "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
timeout 10
ECHO Now running the macro (in a 2nd Tab)...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="mymacro1.iim"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="mymacro2.iim"    
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="mymacro3.iim"

rem Macro Execution completed
ECHO FINISHED!
```

Firefox starts and then loads ALL of the .iim files at once, BUT NONE of them run.

I also tried creating more than one batch file, so that one would run, then call a second one when the 1st one finished ... didn't work!

This code [launch-macros-one-by-one-from-a-batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383576/launch-macros-one-by-one-from-a-batch-file)

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\
start firefox.exe
ping -n 05 127.0.0.1>null
start /wait firefox.exe imacros://run/?m=unlimited1.iim
start /wait firefox.exe imacros://run/?m=unlimited2.iim
```

Started 2 firefox windows but did not run any macros!

@foxdrive - here is the code that I mentioned in the comments @ 9pm or so ....

```
`@ECHO ON
ECHO
ECHO You have 5 sec to close this Window to prevent the Macro from running...
timeout 5
ECHO Start Firefox and wait another 10 seconds...
start /B "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
timeout 10
ECHO Now running the macro (in a 2nd Tab)...
set "tempfile=C:\Users\Public\Documents\iMacros\Macros\flag.txt"
type nul>"%tempfile%"    
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "imacros://run/?m="mymacro1.iim"
:loop1
if exist "%tempfile%" ping -n 10 localhost >nul & goto :loop1

type nul>"%tempfile%"    
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "imacros://run/?m="mymacro2.iim"   
:loop2
if exist "%tempfile%" ping -n 10 localhost >nul & goto :loop2

type nul>"%tempfile%"    
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "imacros://run/?m="mymacro3.iim"
:loop3
if exist "%tempfile%" ping -n 10 localhost >nul & goto :loop3

rem Macro Execution completed
ECHO FINISHED!`
```

Comment: You say you've tried CALL, but you weren't specific about how you used it. That *should* be the right answer. CALL runs a command in the batch file's context and doesn't continue to the next line until that command exists. But in the spirit of "*Any* ideas?", I recommend that you consider leaving the frustrations and primitivity of batch files and cmd behind and start using PowerShell.

Comment: Why don't you use timeout 10 between calls of two iim files ? You have to give some time for a batch to run iim file.

Comment: IceD - each iim file has different run lengths, that change day to day.

Comment: Adi inbar- Thank you for the quick reply. I used CALL instead of the start /b. I will admit I really dont understand the codes uses, meaning (although I did read them) - I will go do a search for "powershell"... I was hoping someone smarter and more code knowledable than myself would have an answer based on what Ive already learned.... I would hate to throw away what Ive learned and accomplished so far... admit its not much, but its a huge accomplishment for me.

Answer (score 3):

Now that the macros delete this temp file when they finish, this should work:

```
@echo off
ECHO You have 5 sec to close this Window to prevent the Macro from running...
timeout 5
ECHO Start Firefox and wait another 10 seconds...
start /B "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
timeout 10
set "tempfile=C:\Users\Public\Documents\iMacros\Macros\flag.txt"
echo macro 1 running
type nul>"%tempfile%"    
start "" /w /b "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="mymacro1.iim"
:loop1
if exist "%tempfile%" ping -n 10 localhost >nul & goto :loop1
echo macro 2 running
type nul>"%tempfile%"    
start "" /w /b "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="mymacro2.iim"    
:loop2
if exist "%tempfile%" ping -n 10 localhost >nul & goto :loop2
echo macro 3 running
type nul>"%tempfile%"    
start "" /w /b C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="mymacro3.iim"
:loop3
if exist "%tempfile%" ping -n 10 localhost >nul & goto :loop3
```

Comment: foxdrive - Thank you for your suggestion. I tried the code you provided and it started firefox, started running MYMACRO1 - when it got to line 8 0f 702, it abruptly started running MYMACRO2 . Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Foxdrive - Last instructions opened 3 firefox windows all at once, and in each the appropriate macro played. Unfortunately this will not work for me, as when multiple firefox windows try to play macros at the same time, error are the norm (pages not filling or not submiting) So I really need to figure out a way to get them to load one at a time, waiting till each finishes before starting the next. A few years ago I used the instr. on this page:  [link](http://forum.iopus.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4888)[/link]  with all of the newer versions of firefox, windows..something is making it not work

Comment: Firefox is returning control to the batch file as soon as the macro starts running.  To stop the next command(s) running straight away you can make the macro delete a temp file when it is done - can it do that?  Like execute `del %temp%\flag.txt` - if it can do that then the batch file can be written to create the file and loop while the file exists.  Each macro can delete the same file when it is done - and the batch file can do the rest. Let me know if the macro has that capability and I'll write something to suit.

Comment: @foxdrive - Yes, I was able to successfully able to delete a txt file. I used the following batch file `start /B "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
    timeout 10
    ECHO Now running the macro (in a 2nd Tab)...
     "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "imacros://run/?m="mymacro1.iim"`  and then used `FILEDELETE NAME=C:\Users\Public\Documents\iMacros\Macros\flag.txt` on the lat line of mymacro1.iim

Comment: Great Tammy!  The batch file in my answer now checks every 10 seconds to see if the file is gone, and will continue to the next one.

Comment: @foxdrive, question - once mymacro1 comes to an end and deletes flag.txt and then moves onto mymacro2..... once flag.txt is deleted, how can mymacro2, mymacro3, mymacro4, etc.. delete it again?

Comment: You add the same FILEDELETE command to the end of each macro, as the file is recreated by the batch file before each macro is launched by the `type nul>"%tempfile%"` command.

Comment: @foxdrive, thank you for answering my question! I like to learn as Im doing it. I tried it as is and it wouldnt work. Firefox loaded and just sat there... so I added your code after some of my exiiting working code (I edited my original post to show you) and the results were.. it loaded firefox (2 tabes) - 1 tab played the macro, the other tab simply stated "imacros://run/?m="mymacro1.iim", it then played mymacro1, completed mymacro1 and then tab 2 went on to say macro2... but didnt load mymacro2 in tab 1... and thats were it sat.

Comment: @foxdrive - ran it exact as it is and Firefox loaded, dos promt says "macro 1 running" .. however its not running. From my working bat, I "think" Firefox has to be called first, as described above in the ( ECHO Start Firefox and wait another 10 seconds.) or else it wont begin to play the macro.

Comment: wow, same results  as the first time 2 tabs, in one played fully to completion mymacro1, while tab 2 simply said "imacros://run/?m="mymacro1.iim" - After mymacro1 played fully, tab 1 stayed at the page of the end of macro1, while tab 2 said "imacros://run/?m="mymacro2.iim" - but did not play macro2

Comment: Im not great withcode... I dont understand most of it actually, but I dont understand why the original javascript approach (illistrated by david poor in the link I gave above), no longer works. I wonder if the original batch file and javascript files could be edited to work with todays versions of firefox and windows... Will await your next instructions, as Im lost without your help! Thanks

Comment: Thanks @foxdrive. Support for macros in firefox is a forum and this question has been asked several times, yet there are no solid answers yet. The same question has been asked on this website as well. Thank you for trying!

Comment: @FOXDRIVE - It worked!!!! You did it! Thank you, Thank you, Thank you! I didnt see the comment about the FILEDELETE ... Or maybe I was too tired and frustrated, whatever the reason.. I came back re-read everything and tried again. KUDOS!!!!!

Comment: That's great! Thanks for coming back to tell us.  I removed several of my comments to clean up the message trail.  Feel free to do the same.