# Calling imacros file inside a perl script

Tags: perl, imacros, browser-automation

I would like to call an iim file from a perl script which tends to automate some browser tasks. If I do what the link says:
http://wiki.imacros.net/Perl
then I need to download the imacros browser which in turns results in a license issue[after 30 days I need to purchase the enterprise edition]
if instead I call it from command line like below:
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  imacros://run/?m=Demo-FillForm.iim
it doesn't work as expected. I want Demo-Fillform.iim to get executed and the control to my perl script to return only when the iim file is fully executed but that is not so. After executing the above sentence ["C:...], control returns immediately.  How can I ensure that control returns to the perl script only when the iim file is fully executed? please help.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, please try to reword the question.

Comment: This could help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157119/create-a-batch-file-to-open-firefox-then-run-a-macro-wait-for-it-to-finish-th

Comment: Kuthbudin pointed you in the right direction, this comment by foxidrive: "Firefox is returning control to the batch file as soon as the macro starts running. To stop the next command(s) running straight away you can make the macro delete a temp file when it is done - can it do that? Like execute del %temp%\flag.txt - if it can do that then the batch file can be written to create the file and loop while the file exists. Each macro can delete the same file when it is done - and the batch file can do the rest."

Comment: Thanks! I will try this in my perl script and let you know if it works. My perl script would loop around till a certain temp file exists. This file will be deleted by the iim script when it completes execution.